# ConvLSTM2D prediction is the same as the image at t-1

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to predict the next image in a sequence of images, and I'm not too sure why LSTMs aren't cutting it for me. My predicted image seems to always be a copy of the image at the previous timestep. This is the model that I used. I also had similar results when using Conv3D on my images, but I'm not too sure why this is so. My input has been normalized to be in range [0,1], and I multiplied my output by 255 because my Ys weren't normalized.

This is my LSTM model

```
lstm = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x,axis=-1),input_shape=X.shape[1:]),
    tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.05),
    tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(25,padding='same',kernel_size=(3,3),return_sequences=True,stateful=False),
    tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(25,padding='same',kernel_size=(3,3),return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(25,padding='same',kernel_size=(3,3),return_sequences=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,padding='same',kernel_size=(1,1),trainable=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.backend.squeeze(x,axis=-1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: 255. * tf.clip_by_value(x,0.,1.))
    ])
```

And this is my Conv3D model

```
conv = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x,axis=-1),input_shape=X.shape[1:]),
    tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.05),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(25,padding='same',data_format='channels_last',kernel_size=(5,3,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(25,padding='same',data_format='channels_last',kernel_size=(5,3,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(1,padding='same',data_format='channels_last',kernel_size=(1,1,1), trainable=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.backend.squeeze(x,axis=-1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,kernel_size=(1,1),data_format='channels_first',trainable=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.backend.squeeze(x,axis=-3)),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: 255. * tf.clip_by_value(x,0.,1.))
    ])
```

I tried making a SSIM loss function but it makes my model predict that the next image will be **super bright**, and performs much worse than simply using mse.

This is the loss function I made. I know it looks extreme but all my images are very similar in structure to each other, so I believe this harshness is warranted. There were no NaN errors during training.

```
def custom_err(y_true,y_pred):
    #ssim has range [-1,1], with -1 being the worst and 1 being the best
    def SSIM(y_true,y_pred):
        ssim= tf.image.ssim(tf.expand_dims(y_true,-1),tf.expand_dims(y_pred,-1),255.)
        return ssim
    ssim=SSIM(y_true,y_pred)
    return 10**(abs(ssim - 1) * 20) - 1
```

Comment: hi @Yeo Zhi Long, kindly provide the complete reproducible code and other necessary details.